# CollectionView ItemHeight is big than Collectionview Height

Tags: ios, swift

Thanks to help.

[image]

[image]

As shown in the above,CollectionView ItemSize.height is big than CollectionView.height.
And I just set the itemSize in viewDidLayoutSubviews()

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    resizeCollectionView(size: collectionView.frame.size)
}

private func resizeCollectionView(size: CGSize){
    print("collectionViewSize:\(size)")
    print("viewSize:\(view.frame.size)")
    if let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: size.width, height: collectionView.frame.size.height)
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        collectionView?.layoutIfNeeded()
        print("itemSize:\(layout.itemSize)")
    }
}
```

The print show that CollectionViewSize is equal ItemSize, But the actual, itemSize always big than CollectioinViewSize.

Comment: I try to use A fixed value like : var itemHeight = view.frame.height - titleTopView.frame.maxY - tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.height, it will not change. But I don't know why collectionView.frame.height can not use.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: yourWidth, height: yourCollectionView.bounds.height)
}
```